# Tables with mixed ON DELETE CASCADE and ON DELETE RESTRICT, rule set with recursion?

Tags: mysql, delete, recursive, cascade

Not sure if this is a generic question, but unless not, this is **MySQL 5.6**.

We have a database consisting of ~300 tables, INNODB, all connected with proper foreign keys. One of these tables can be seen as the parent. My desired end result is that I can execute one delete on this table, and have all related information in all other 300 tables deleted as well.

However, the declared foreign keys are a mix of RESTRICT and CASCADE for ON DELETE and I'm trying to understand the rule set when these are applied in recursion.

I've been trying to find information on this, but no luck. Testing appears to indicate that RESTRICT blocks a CASCADE, but not *necessarily*. Consider this example:

> Tables: A, B, C
>   B -> A (ON DELETE CASCADE)
>   C -> A (ON DELETE CASCADE)
>   C -> B (ON DELETE RESTRICT)

In this example, rows from B and C are deleted when A is deleted. However, since C -> B has a RESTRICT one could think that matching rows would block a CASCADE. But this is not the case. However, if I add an additional table D like this:

> Tables: A, B, C, D
>   B -> A (ON DELETE CASCADE)
>   C -> A (ON DELETE CASCADE)
>   C -> B (ON DELETE RESTRICT)
>   D -> C (ON DELETE RESTRICT)

A delete from A is blocked by the RESTRICT from D to C.

A simple approach would be to simply use CASCADE everywhere, but I'm curious about the rule set. Or if the behaviour is either implementation dependent or simply undefined.

Is it based on level of depth of the CASCADING? That is, the shortest path determines the effective ON DELETE rule to use? What if multiple paths have the same length, with different rules?

Comment: Are you sure the case with 3 tables (A, B, C) succeeds always?

Comment: [dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=d285cd03d20104400770df648744b2f7) 3 cases, some fail, some succeed

Comment: By 3 cases, are you talking about the 3 possible cases you can have with rows in this example? My assumption here was was 3 tables will all non-nullable fields, with rows that make use of the foreign keys.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the general rule set though, without regard to the rows. On a logical level. Ultimately, I want to implement an algorithm that by just analysing the tables' structure can verify whether a delete will *always* be a success, or not (only succeeding under some conditions is a fail).

Comment: Yes, with 3 cases I meant the specific inserts. Deleting `aid=1` and `aid=2` fail. Deleting `aid=3` succeeds. The desgin is exactly as your question, 3 tables, not nullable columns, and FKs from (B->A, C->B, C->A).

Comment: About a general algorithm, I'm not really sure. If all the FKs have `ON DELETE CASCADE`, I think success is guaranteed. Any other design, I'm not sure but will probably fail under some cases.

Comment: Thanks, though untested, I'd expect delete to propagate with all being ON DELETE CASCADE. How it works generally though with a large graph of tables with a mix of RESTRICT and CASCADE, no information can be found. I will have to assume that it is implementation dependant and/or even undefined. Fortunately, I worked around my problem. With some graphs algorithms I isolated those tables that *must* have cascade on delete for their foreign keys, and those where it is optional. I can then kind of brute force a full delete by traversering a key set of tables and executing explicit deletes.

Comment: The flaw with the ABC example is that it doesn't actually appear to prove anything.   If a delete from A cascades to C (and deletes the row from C), there is at that point no C->B row that would restrict the deletion from B, so deletion from B via the cascade from A would be entirely valid.  Whether this is indicative of awareness on the part of InnoDB or merely a quirk of declaration order or another aspect of the implementation is not clear, but I would say this should indeed succeed, because no constraint is actually violated by deleting from A in this example.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I agree, in this example this delete should CASCADE. However, from examining my 300-table setup I came to the conclusion that other similar scenarios *were* blocked due to there existing a RESTRICT like C->B. Like if it was up to chance, depending what foreign keys MySQL decided to "follow" first. Like I wrote in a previous comment, I have dedided to treat this as an "undefined" condition and worked around the problem.

Comment: I think it would be great if we could get to the bottom of this, authoritatively, since it seems like a good question.  Do you have an MCVE of a case similar to ABC that does restrict even though an alternative exists that could theoretically have prevented it via a cascade?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot posted an answer with my discoveries after some more testing

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to create a test case that at least for **MySQL 5.6** demonstrates, for all intents and purposes, that the behaviour is undefined. Consider these 3 examples creating a "diamond"-shape between A, B, C and D.

**Example 1**

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `b` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    a INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES a (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `c` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    a INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES a (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `d` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    b INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    c INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES b (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES c (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO a VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO c VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO d VALUES (1, 1, 1);

DELETE FROM a;
```

Delete from **a** is successful as expected, as all keys are **CASCADE**.

**Example 2**

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `b` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    a INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES a (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `c` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    a INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES a (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `d` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    b INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    c INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES b (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES c (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
) ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO a VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO c VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO d VALUES (1, 1, 1);

DELETE FROM a;
```

Notice that **d** now has a **RESTRICT** to **c**. I would consider this case ambiguous as it forces you to consider which foreign key "wins". **CASCADE** or **RESTICT**, what is picked?

The result is that all rows are deleted.

**Example 3**

```
CREATE TABLE `a` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `b` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    a INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES a (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `c` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    a INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (a) REFERENCES a (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE `d` (
    id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    b INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    c INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES b (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES c (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE = INNODB;

INSERT INTO a VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO b VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO c VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO d VALUES (1, 1, 1);

DELETE FROM a;
```

Notice that the only difference is the change of what foreign key is **RESTRICT** from **d**. This example however, fails with

> Error Code: 1451
>   Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hello`.`d`, CONSTRAINT `d_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `b` (`id`))

While logically, it's the same as **Example 2**. Without having looked at the source code of **MySQL**, I strongly suspect that the foreign keys are "applied" in lexical order based on their name. This is also the order the foreign keys are listed by **mysqldump**.

Without knowing whether what I'm testing here has a defined behaviour or not based on a higher logic, it's hard to know if this demonstrates either a bug, or simply the behaviour in **MySQL**.

Regardless, as it stands, this example shows that in practical terms I'd say that for all intents and purposes, when having mixed **CASCADE** and **RESTRICT**, the behaviour is **undefined** as it's not in any way sound that you should depend on the names given to foreign keys.

Comment: Another possible explaination is that deletion is performed by something similar to a depth-first traversal that fails whenever a **RESTRICT** is encountered. Traversal itself could possibly make use of a lexical order. Would need to look at source code. Still, as close to undefined as it gets in my opinion.